# How To: Let users paste cells from another excel instance (Ctrl+V,...) but paste only values

Tags: excel, vba

**EDITED WITH PROGRESS**

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I am working on a big excel file that does some calculations for me and my colleagues. Because the calculation data is a lot and is entered in Ranges (like "A1:H8"), not single cells (like "A1","C1",...), I want the users to be able to copy data from the same or another excel instance to my file.

**The problem (edited):**

The problem is, that just pasting cells formats the target cells (even if they are protected against formatting) and this has to be avoided. I searched through a lot of online discussions and finally made my own code, that allows me to copy and paste between two excel files in the same excel instance. Sadly, it does not work, if I copied the cells from another instance.

**The code:**

This is the code I use in "ThisWorkbook":

```vb
Sub PasteValuesOnly()
'if cells are pasted in named worksheets, only values are pasted
'is linked to Ctrl+V in options of macro menu

On Error GoTo err_handler

    Dim Target As Range

    Set Target = Selection

    If Target.Parent.Name <> "Table1" Then

        Selection.PasteSpecial

    Else

        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    End If

err_handler:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

**The system:**

- Windows 7
- Excel 2010

**What I tried besides my code (new progress):**

As mentioned in the comments, I know [Siddharth Rout's solution](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/09/17/vba-excelallow-paste-special-only/) for only letting the users paste values, but I can't get it to work (not even in a fresh file when copying and pasting inside one Excel instance). I tried it for the whole workbook and for one single sheet.

**What would help (edited):**

It would be very helpful, if you could tell me how to optimize my code, so it works for two instances as well. If you know what is to do when I have an error with `UndoList = Application.CommandBars(“Standard”).Controls(“&Undo”).List(1)` in Siddharth Rout's solution with Excel 2010, this would be helpful, too.
Otherwise I would like every solution, that let's my users paste like they ever do, but prevent them from formatting the cells while pasting.

Thank you in advance

RaspiManu

Comment: see: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/09/17/vba-excelallow-paste-special-only/

Comment: Thank you very much for that link, but I already knew it and couldn't get it to work. I will try again as soon as possible. Do you have any other idea for modifying my code?

Comment: I tried it again... At first I set up a new file and only entered Code I of Siddharth Rout in "ThisWorkbook". After that I tried Code II in "Sheet1", also in a new file. Both of the options did not work. Maybe it's because of my Excel 2010. While debugging it stopped at `UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)`. Could you please help me getting it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long hours of searching the internet, I found [the solution of Donna Landy (Bella_Donna)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-you-lock-formats-but-allow-data-entry/afccc43e-e191-417f-826c-d10a464a1b9a?page=4) in the microsoft forum. Her code is simple and works for CTRL+C / CTRL+V, Copy and Paste over Right Click Menu, Drag'n'Drop and even with two excel instances.

Because it starts on every single cell change and goes back to the cell or range that was changed, I slightly optimized it for my needs. Now, users that enter a list manually won't have to press "Enter" two times every time, they want to get to the next line below.

Assuming, the standard user will normally copy and paste, if there is a range of data, he or she does not want to retype, I changed the code, so the module sub only gets activated, if more than one cell has been changed (see below).

**The solution:**

In every worksheet, that has to be protected against formatting (modified):

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'activates format protection when changing a range

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then                      'If more than one cell has been changed...
        Call Worksheet_Change_Protected(Target)         '...activating protection
    End If

End Sub
```

In a module (unmodified):

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change_Protected(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Prevents user blithely obliterating in-cell formatting by undoing their paste and pasting the value

    'Donna Landy 26.11.2018

    'May be freely copied - hat tip appreciated :)

    Dim SavedVal As Variant

    On Error GoTo ErrHan

    'Save the pasted value for later

    SavedVal = Target.Value

    'Switch off events to prevent infinite loop

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Undo the user's paste

    Application.Undo

    'Set target value

    Target.Value = SavedVal

ErrExit:

    'Remember to re-enable events

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Exit Sub

ErrHan:

    Resume ErrExit

End Sub
```

**Thank you very much, Donna Landy!**

Comment: This is very helpful. But "undo" will always be unavailable even if a user types something manually in a cell. Imagine if a user changed a number and wanted to revert back a change or pasted some info over another by mistake and wanted to undo, it would be so annoying! Users need to be completely understanding that "undo" "has been disabled" for a very compelling reason and that they should adapt to the fact that they must ALWAYS be alert not to make a mistake. Other than this, I think it's a nice solution.